# Are these Deutsche Bahn train seats side-by-side?

Tags: trains, germany, seating, deutsche-bahn

I booked two tickets on the direct Deutsche Bahn (ICE 93) train from Berlin to Vienna and the seat information is shown as - **"Side-by-side seats Carriage 27, seats 13, 15"**. I would normally have expected the seat numbers to be continuous, e.g. "13, 14" or "14, 15", although I have never travelled by train in Germany so do not know the seat number system.

I booked the tickets via Trainline EU and I asked them. Their reply was:

> Unfortunately, we don't have access to the seat plan of this train, so
>   there is no way for me to confirm or deny if you are next to each
>   other. Usually, when you're booking for multiple passengers at the
>   same time, the system automatically tries to put them together(if
>   possible), or the at the very least close to one another.

Could someone confirm that the seats are indeed side-by-side (and also not separated by the aisle)? Also, if anyone could show the seats on a seating plan that would be helpful.

Edit: This is the same train on a different date:
[image]

Comment: https://www.seat61.com/Europe-train-seat-plans.htm Seat61 is your friend for such queries.

Comment: @DumbCoder I just looked at that and couldn't find ICE 93.

Comment: Could you tell us the date and time? ICE 93 is neither found by "zugfinder.de" nor on http://www.grahnert.de/fernbahn/reihung/reih0043.html which contains information about the train types of specific services.

Comment: @DCTLib Looks as though ICE 93 is a new addition in the December timetable change. A bahn.de search for Berlin-Vienna after 9 December brings it up (depart 10:05, arrive 17:45).

Comment: Related: [How do DB seat numbers work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101517/how-do-db-seat-numbers-work)

Comment: It should be noted that DB themselves sometimes don't know (or care). I've had it on several occasions that I booked a seat only to be told: _"Oh yes, we are now on ICE4, and the seats are different than from ICE3, we didn't update the booking system yet"_.   (that being 2 months after the switch)

Comment: @Damon - Good to know. I'll check in advance. Similar thing happened to me on Eurostar recently. Booked in advance and then the seats were changed. Asked why, the train manager said it sometimes happens if you book well in advance and he didn't know why. Craziest thing was that my original seats were in the next carriage which was completely empty! We moved to those seats straight away.

Comment: The Deutsch Bahn seat numbering system is far from logical anyway. It used to make sense in th egood old days when there were only compartment cars ("Abteilwagen"): The first compartment had seats 11-16, the second 21-26, then 31-36, and so on. With the introduction of "Großraumwagen", they for some reason tried to stick with the same numbers even though leaving out 17,18,19, 20 makes no sense and traditionally neighboured groups of six do not fit well with rows of four seats. For sentient observers, the seat numbers appear to jump somewhat erratically.

Comment: 93 is not the train type but the train-equivalent of a flight number.

Comment: I'll just say that I've seen jumps by 2 in many ICEs both by DB and OEBB - so this shouldn't be too worrisome in my experience. *Why* they do that is a mystery to me though.

Comment: Note you can also use the community project https://bahn.expert/ and search for your train number (and day) there, [here an example](https://bahn.expert/details/ICE%20100/2023-11-30T22:33:58.000Z/?station=8500010). There is a note of the train type (like ICE 3, ICE 4 etc. e.g.) with a link that leads you to the specification of it, which has the whole seating plan in a convenient PDF: An example: https://bahn.expert/WRSheets/412.13.pdf

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check this by trying to book a reservation on bahn.de - Select "Reservation only" on the main page, then search for your train, try to make a reservation (without logging in), click on "select seat" and the layout of the coach will be shown.

For the 20th of December, an ICE train type is used for which seats 13 and 15 are next to each other and appear to be 1st class in Coach 27. Due to copyright reasons, I cannot include the seat plan shown on bahn.de here.

I am not sure if that is the case for all ICE types, but normally, seats 15 and 13 should be next to each other. The numbering scheme comes from the old days of vis-a-vis compartment seating and was just continued to be used when compartments were no longer used.

Comment: Does it say which type of ICE train it is? The plans on seat61 show that they have different layouts, some of which have 13 and 15 adjacent in 2nd class (as per the screenshot above), some don't...

Comment: @NickC I've updated the screenshot to show first class selection (which my booking is).

Comment: @NickC In my experience, bahn.de never tells you the concrete ICE train type (ICE 1, ICE 2, ICE 3, Velaro D, ICE-T, ...), which I find quite annoying (as the location of the seats reserved for status customers depends on the train type).

Comment: @camden_kid I've used a bit of deduction, posted as an answer as it was too much for a comment

Comment: "Due to copyright reasons" According to which law or jurisdiction? Why do you think that DeutscheBahn would sue it's user for using a seat visualization in a discussion board?

Comment: We already have a generic question about seat number arrangments in German trains and they vary quite a bit. Even within the same train, different waggons may use different numbering systems. Trying to book the seats and looking at the seat plan offered by the DB reservation system will work, but you can't make any conclusions only based on the train type. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101517/how-do-db-seat-numbers-work

Comment: @FooBar because he doesn’t have the legal rights to licence the image as CS-by-CA 3.0...? So pretty much every law or jurisdiction which prevents relicencing work you do not own!

Comment: @FooBar I was thinking the same... ;)

Comment: While the number range of seat numbers is different depending on train types, I am not aware of any ICE that has consecutive seat numbers in the _Grossraumabteil_ next to each other. It's always odd on one and even on the other side. Like house numbers on German streets.

Comment: I get that you may not be able to embed an image, could you at least include a link to where you found it? That would be very helpful to the *ahem* more lazy among us...

Comment: @Tim: You can exclude content from being licensed under CC BY-SA by saying so (and ideally using quote markup in addition). In that case, your use of the content has to be allowed by the default copyright laws (see quoting laws). -- In the case of DB train layouts for reservation, I would argue that they can’t be copyrighted to begin with (threshold of originality) -- but even if they are, quoting them in the context of this answer should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @unor the image uploaded message suggests differently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ENh.jpg

Comment: @Tim: Yes, that’s the same message that is also in the footer on each SE page, but it’s still allowed to quote from books, documentation sites etc. (which aren’t licensed under CC BY-SA) without licensing the quotes under CC BY-SA that way. -- I don’t know if it makes a legal difference whether the image is hosted on imgur or somewhere else, though.

Comment: @unor (3 comments up) I actually have my doubts you can just exclude content from CC-BY-SA by just saying so. On [meta.SO] (for example) you can find discussion of some cases where a poster included text saying that part or all of the post was not covered by CC-BY-SA, but the prevailing wisdom (which I believe) seems to be that these statements have no legal weight and the content is under CC-BY-SA anyway. But you're right that it's fine to include quotes, which is probably justified by fair use in the US, and perhaps the same exemption might apply to certain images.

Comment: @Tim : Isn't it fair use if you use it only for discussion/analysis purposes?

Comment: Fair use and quotation laws differ between countries. For example, in Sweden there is *no quotation right whatsoever for images*. German laws [seem more relaxed](http://copyrightblog.kluweriplaw.com/2017/11/27/pictorial-quotation-incidental-use-13-quotations-many-according-austrian-court/) on this topic but probably not as relaxed as the US Fair Use rules (assuming DCTLib is indeed situated in Germany, otherwise her jurisdiction will matter).

Comment: @FreeMan I would have loved to include a link, but the Deutsche Bahn Booking system is notorous for equipping all links with session keys (or similar data) so that they expire very quickly. A deep link to the coach layout image may have worked, but there have been lawsuits about deep linking images in Germany that have been lost by the linker. Quotation for discussion/analysis is fine, but I know that at least in the academic context, you cannot quote whole pictures in Germany (without permission). And since the layout of one coach seating layout is one such picture, I did not want to risk it.

Comment: Covered by copyright is also not the seating layout itself, but the artistic expression of how this is represented in an image is covered at least by German copyright (Urheberrecht) laws. So what would certainly be OK would be to redraw the layout using my own Draw/Paint/Inkscape skills and uploading the image here, which I didn't do for time reasons. Since my answer includes how to obtain the image yourself (by using the bahn.de website), I thought that it was enough.

Comment: @DCTLib - wow, I didn't mean to spark such a comment storm! Your reasons are perfectly valid and I have no desire to see you in court, money out of pocket or in jail!

Comment: @FreeMan Oh, Admittedly, the answer was to all of the comments above here. Just the first sentence of my comment was a reply to you specifically.

Answer (score 8):

Using the seating plans on seat61.com, and a bit of deduction:

If it's an ICE 2 or ICE-T-7, then seats 13 and 15 in car 27 are adjacent.

(ICE 1 & 4 don't have car 27. In ICE 3 and ICE-T-5, car 27 is 2nd class only, so it can't be any of those types)

Answer (score 3):

Both seats are indeed adjacent:

[image]

Comment: This will be a very good answer if you can clarify how you found this diagram, to make it clear that it does apply to the train in the question question. Without that, all you're showing is a diagram of *some* train where seats 13 and 15 are adjacent.

Comment: The diagram contributed by Diego above can be found during reservation through the Deutsche Bahn website (available in English). Here you can see a seat map and select your seats. This happens in the stage before you confirm your reservation and pay, so can be done even when booking through another website.